# What permission can I use for ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE intents?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-broadcast

A security review flagged the use of `sendBroadcast` calls in our App without a permission parameter. We only use sendBroadcast to invoke the Android Media Scanner, and I don't think that app will have any unique permissions.

Is there a system permission I can use? Otherwise, what stops other apps potentially receiving these broadcasts also?

Comment: Considering that this broadcast simply points out a file that other apps could find by other means, this does not seem to be an actual security problem. "what stops other apps potentially receiving these broadcasts also?" -- nothing, but since the point behind the broadcast is to make the content available to any other interested app, what's the real problem?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response, I agree in this case there is nothing to hide, and it doesn't make sense. I'll pass that on. What if I had something I wanted to hide though, like for example a service that receives FCM notifications. Does it make sense there to specify a permissions filter? Does the firebase messaging system on Android have a permission I could use as a filter? Is there a general way to figure that out for system apps/services?

Comment: Also, please write up your comment as a question, and I'll mark it as answered :)

Comment: "Does it make sense there to specify a permissions filter?" -- you aren't sending the broadcasts in that scenario. Play Services is. And there it is not a true "broadcast", insofar as the `Intent` will have the `ComponentName` of your receiver in it, so other parties will not be able to receive it. "Is there a general way to figure that out for system apps/services?" -- as a sender of a broadcast? In principle you could try to come up with a value by puttering through the AOSP code, but I would not rely upon that.

Comment: Thanks so much for these detailed answers, this is really useful and helpful! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a system permission I can use?

There is no documented permission that you could apply that would restrict the recipients yet ensure that the `MediaStore` receives it.

> Otherwise, what stops other apps potentially receiving these broadcasts also?

Nothing. And in this particular case, there is no real problem. The point of `ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE` is to add publicly-visible content to the `MediaStore`. Most other apps will find out about that by keeping tabs on the `MediaStore`. Another app could listen for this broadcast, and perhaps find out about the content a few milliseconds earlier than others.